# How can I sync Logic Pro's tempo (click) with a mp3 containing a song?

Tags: software, logic-pro

I'd like to record a few instruments on the original mp3 track of a song...
I just can't find how to match bpm and click once imported the mp3 in logic.

Comment: This question is more suited to avp.so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of logic you're using (I have logic 8), but have you tried inserting a bpm counter?

for the track you're interested in...

inserts -> metering -> bpm counter -> stereo

then play the track, and it should find the beats per minute after a few seconds...

a video tutorial on youtube :